# How to install Bing.Maps SDK

Tags: winrt-xaml

Kinda new to VS2012 for installing Bing.Maps SDK

I have downloaded this from this from:
BingMaps SDK 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ebc98390-5320-4088-a2b5-8f276e4530f9

It wont install when I double click it, there is msg " Use this app for all .vsix files"  so What tool I need to use to install it in VS2012?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading .VSIX file, double click on that file. If you are prompt to choose app to run, choose Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Thanks. This is really unexpected. To open this app , use Ms vs version selector. There is no Vs2012. Thanks for the hints. Have installed it and will test it out soon.